# Casino Roulette Game not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

http://csdev.cegep-heritage.qc.ca/students/cguigue/primordialCasino/game.html

supposed to click on the spin button and it should start the wheel spinning as well as changed the text on the screen in my displayArea, though when i click spin nothing happens,

getting undefined type error on the following code and not sure as to why

```
$('#wheel').rotate({
        angle: 0,
        animateTo: 2520,
        duration: 4000
    });
```

it says it isn't a function... :S
also...

```
if(currentGame.place == 0 && cellText == 0)
            {
                currentGame.setBet(betAmount * 40); 
            }

function rouletteGame(num, even, col)
{
this.place = num;
this.isEven = even;
this.colour = col;
this.win = 0;
this.hasBet = false;
this.setBet = function(bet)
{
    this.win += bet;
    this.hasBet = true;
}
```

says currentGame.place is undefined
but im initializing it in a for loop and its calling my above function...

```
 for (var i = 1; i < rouletteWheel.length; ++i)
{
    place = i;

    if(i % 2 == 1)
    {
        isEven = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isEven = true;
    }

    if( i = red[count])
    {
        colour = "red";
        ++count;
    }
    else
    {
        colour = "black";   
    }

    rouletteWheel[i] = new rouletteGame(place, isEven, colour);
}// for ()
```

Comment: What is not a function, `rotate()`? Have you included a plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

`.rotate()` is not a built-in JQuery plugin. You will need to download or link the plugin in order for it to work. Add the following in your  element of the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

and see if that helps. with the first part of your problem.

As for the second part, I'm not sure if Javascript works this way too (I think it does), but you should create the new roulette game outside of the loop, and only change the values inside. Otherwise you are only creating a new roulette game for use within the scope of the for loop, not outside.

May want to check the documentation for this, as I'm not 100% positive about it. I just know it's how most other languages work.